# Stretchable square brackets outside math environment

Tags: brackets

I would like use stretchable square brackets outside of a math environment. Ideally, I would like to use `\left[ blah \right.` right in my text.

Is it possible ? How ?

Note : I would like to be able to include new environment in place of my "blah", like this :

```
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
    blah \\
    blah
\end{array}
\right.
```

Example #1 :

[image]

Comment: Actually, my goal is to display "plain language programatic diagram" to describe algorithms with english words. The standard I have to use (for school) use a lot of imbricated square brackets in order to represent them. I hope it's clear. If not, let me know and I'll publish a sample. The idea is that I don't want to use a lot of `\mbox{blah}` as the overwhelming majority of the content will be text.

Comment: You might be better off showing an example. You could, of course, make a command which wraps its arguments in `\mbox`es and parentheses to cut down the clutter. You may also want to look into the various algorithm/pseudocode environments, such as `algorithm2e.sty` or `pseudocode.sty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution using TiKZ which gets you a look more or less as you describe.

### Preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  grouping/.style={inner sep=2pt, baseline=0ex, left delimiter={[}},
  grouplabel/.style={anchor=west, yshift=0.125\baselineskip}
}

\newlength\groupinglength
\setlength\groupinglength{\textwidth}

\def\BEGIN #1 \END{%
  \bgroup
  \addtolength\groupinglength{-1ex}%
  \hspace*{1.5ex}%
  \tikz \node [grouping] {\hspace{-0.5ex}\parbox{\groupinglength}{#1}};%
  \egroup
}

\newcommand\labelledgroup[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every left delimiter/.style={yshift=-0.1\baselineskip}]
    \addtolength\groupinglength{-1ex}%
    \node [grouping, inner ysep=0.5\baselineskip] (block) {%
      \parbox{\groupinglength}{#2}%
    };    
    \node [grouplabel] at (block.north west) {#1};
    \node [grouplabel] at (block.south west) {#3};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\IF[2]{\labelledgroup{if #1}{#2}{}}
\newcommand\ELSE[1]{\\[-0.6\baselineskip]\labelledgroup{else}{#1}{end}}
```

These definitions define macros to produce code blocks, which have a uniformly customizable delimiter on the left. Each distinct line of code, or code block, should be ended with an end-of-line. We define the `\IF` and `\ELSE` block in terms of a generic code block, which starts off (and conceivably ends, as well) with some label aligned with the top of the delimiter. You could use similar code to define a **repeat ... until** code block, or a **procedure ... return** block. The various dimensions were picked more or less arbitrarily, except for the cases of `0.5\baselineskip`.

### Document body

```
\begin{document}

\BEGIN 
  Get the height of the box \texttt{hBox} \\
  Get the width of the box \texttt{wBox} \\
  Get the length of the box \texttt{lBox} \\
  $\texttt{vol} = \texttt{hBox} \times \texttt{wBox} \times \texttt{lBox}$ \\
  \IF {$\texttt{vol} > 10$}%
    {Display \textit{``Your box is too big''}}  
  \ELSE
    {Display \textit{``Your box is right-sized''}}  \\
\END

\end{document}
```

As it's currently defined, `\BEGIN ... \END` will complain if there's a blank line. There are a few ways to get around that (*e.g.* simply by using different syntax); I've written it in this way instead to keep things simpler and to emulate some of the syntax for existing algorithm/pseudocode packages.

### Result

[image: typeset pseudocode]

Edit the code (*e.g.* remove the "end" in the definition of `\ELSE`) and define other blocks (perhaps things like `\FOR` and `\WHILE`) to get the sort of algorithm presentation that you want.

Comment: Thank you ! I used the dirtier `\newcommand\ELSE{\hspace*{-1.5ex}- else \\}` instead and found it way more reliable when using in cascade. Use like that : `\IF{cond}{code if true\\ \ELSE code if false \\}`.

Answer (score 3):

First a basic solution followed by a fancy solution below.

I had originally designed this to have square brackets on both sides (which I have left, but just commented that portion). So `\bracs` was intended to be used when you have paragraphs, and `\bracs*` for things like tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bracs}{s m}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \ensuremath{\left[\vphantom{\text{#2}}\right.}%
    \text{#2}%
    %\ensuremath{\left.\vphantom{\text{#2}}\right]}%
}{%
    \ensuremath{\left[\vphantom{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{#2}}\right.}%
    \parbox{0.95\linewidth}{#2}%
    %\ensuremath{\left.\vphantom{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{#2}}\right]}%

}}%

\begin{document}
\bracs{
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Get the height of the box hBox \\
    Get the width of the box wBox \\
    Get the length of the box lBox \\
    vol = hBox * wBox * lBox\\
    \bracs{
       \begin{tabular}{l}
          if vol $>$ 10
             Display "Your box is too big"\\
          else\\
             Display "Your box is right-sized"\\
       \end{tabular}
    }
\end{tabular}
}

\bigskip
\bracs{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

As egreg mentions, `tabular` is the text mode environment so that is what is used here.

[image]

---

**Update:** You can also do this with the help of [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) along with `tikz` to get fancy if you so desire:

[image]

I have added a frame using `mdframed` but disabled the top, right, and bottom frame, and used an `tikz` arrow style to produce the top portion of the bracket.

The `\BracS` macro here accepts an additional parameter to control the background color if you choose to (default is `yellow!20`).  See [the `xcolor` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor) for more options on colors.
There are a few obvious options here that you can tweak including the line color, and width. You can also change that each time if you so choose by passing in the entire `tikzsetting` line as in

```
\BracS[yellow!20,tikzsetting={draw=blue, line width=3pt,|-|}]
```

Note that the color must be the first specified parameter -- the order of any others will just take the last value for a particular option.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,xcolor=true]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{BracStyle}{%
    leftmargin=2ex,%
    topline=false,%
    rightline=false,%
    bottomline=false,% 
    backgroundcolor=yellow!20,%
    tikzsetting={draw=red, line width=3pt,|-|},%
}%
\newcommand{\BracS}[2][yellow!20]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=BracStyle,backgroundcolor=#1]%
        {#2}%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%


\begin{document}
\BracS{% default to yellow!20 background
    \begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
        Get the height of the box hBox \\
        Get the width of the box wBox \\
        Get the length of the box lBox \\
        vol = hBox * wBox * lBox\\
        \BracS[blue!20]{
           \begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
              if vol $>$ 10\\
                 Display "Your box is too big"\\
              else\\
                 Display "Your box is right-sized"\\
           \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tabular` in math mode. So

```
\newenvironment{delimitedtabular}[4][c]
  {\def\rightdelim{#3}$\left#2\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#4@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}\right\rightdelim$}
```

will allow you to say

```
\begin{delimitedtabular}\{\}{c}
first\\
second\\
third
\end{delimitedtabular}
```

in text mode (the delimiters are braces. Also `\begin{delimitedtabular}[t]` or `\begin{delimitedtabular}[b]` are allowed. The first two arguments are the delimiters

```
\begin{delimitedtabular}(){cc}
```

will use parentheses. A missing delimiter can be input as `.`: for example,

```
\begin{delimitedtabular}\{.{cc}
```

will draw only a left brace.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work here : "Illegal parameter number in definition of \enddelimitedtabular.", "Missing delimiter (. inserted)." and "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.".

Comment: I made a very stupid error, sorry.

Comment: Interesting that one is required to save an argument for use in the end of the environment (`#3` in this case). Didn't know that.