# Brace diagram in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I apologize if this has already been covered in some other posts, but I couldn't find it anywhere and I'm not even sure if "brace diagram" is the correct name in English.

I have found some examples of probability trees, and some others that are close (like this: [Draw Curly Braces in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/draw-curly-braces-in-tikz)), but while playing with them I couldn't get the correct output (The part of the first "text here" when out of boundaries into the brace).

What I'm trying to do is something like this with `TikZ`:

[image]

I know there are some ways to do this with mathmode, but I'm really interested in learning a little more about `TikZ` and how it works for diagrams like this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to post your TikZ code (in a working example) so that people can check it out and perhaps understand why it's not doing what you want.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I don't have a `tikzpicture` code, that's why I have a graphic representation of what I'm trying to achieve.  I want to know how this could be done with `tikz`.

Comment: If I'm correctly reading your question, you do have tikz code--it just doesn't give the right output: "The first part of 'text here' went out of the boundaries into the brace."

Comment: @CharlesStaats it is the code in the linked question mentioned.  I was just playing around with it changing the p1 for "text here" and as I mentioned, it went out of bounds

Comment: First, that particular problem will probably be solved by adding the key `left` to the relevant `node`, as in `node [left,black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$}`; you will probably also need to adjust the `xshift` value after doing this. Second, braces in `TikZ` are generally used to add labels after the "main objects" have already been placed. Using them as part of the "structure" of a tree is certainly possible, but it hardly seems worth the effort when the `cases` environment is available.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110391/5872) should also be helpful

Comment: See also: [Making Curly Braces with Tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230566/making-curly-braces-with-tikz)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (main) {Text here};
\begin{scope}[node distance=1em]
    \node [right=of main] (t2) {Some text2};
    \node [above=of t2]   (t1) {Some text1};
    \node [below=of t2]   (t3) {Some text3};
\end{scope}
 \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (t1.north west) -- (t3.south west);

\begin{scope}[node distance=.5em]
    \node [right =of t1,yshift= .5em] (st2) {Some text 1.2};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=-.5em] (st3) {Some text 1.3};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=  1.5em] (st1) {Some text 1.1};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift= -1.5em] (st4) {Some text 1.4};
\end{scope}
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (st1.north west) -- (st4.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Why `tikz`? Why not simply `cases` in an equation?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \text{some text} \begin{cases}
    \text{some text}_1 & 
    \begin{cases}
      \text{text 1.1}\\
      \text{text 1.2}\\
      \text{text 1.3}\\
      \text{text 1.4}
    \end{cases}
    \\
    \text{some text}_2\\
    \text{some text}_3
  \end{cases}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, because as I stated in my question, I'm trying to learn how to do this with `Tikz`

Comment: @MarioS.E. May be there is no pressing need for TikZ in this example without a sample TikZ code unless you need something fancy

Comment: The result is wrong with this code. You don't get the example given in the question.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Did you mean the spacing between `text2` and `text3` is not consistent with the spacing between `text1` and `text2`?

Comment: @AlainMatthes One could simply `\smash` the inner `cases` environment.

Answer (score 13):

The `schemata` package is designed just for these brace diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{schemata}
\newcommand\AB[2]{\schema{\schemabox{#1}}{\schemabox{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\AB{text here}
{
\AB{Some text 1}
{
text 1.1 \\ 
text 1.2 \\ 
text 1.3 \\ 
text 1.4
}\\
Some text 2 \\ 
Some text 3
}  

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: This is actually a great answer!

Answer (score 11):

An answer using the `matrix` library (updated according to @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment in @Alex's answer):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

\centering
text here
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1.5ex}, % shorten space b/w brace and text
    column 1/.style={anchor=base west}, % left-align column 1
    row sep=6ex, % consistent row spacing
    baseline={($(M.center)+(0,-.5ex)$)} % mid-align 'some text' and matrix 
  }

  \matrix(M)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=\{]
  {
    \text{some text}_1 
      \smash{
      \begin{cases}
        \text{text 1.1}\\
        \text{text 1.2}\\
        \text{text 1.3}\\
        \text{text 1.4}        
      \end{cases}
      }\\
    \text{some text}_2\\
    \text{some text}_3\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, `\matrix` cannot be nested...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, unfortunately...