# How to use braces to achieve branch structure diagram

Tags: braces

[image]

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont{宋体} 
\usepackage{amsmath,mathptmx}

\begin{document}
$
\text{《内经》学术体系}
\begin{cases}
\text{医学理论}
        \begin{cases}
                \text{藏象}
                    \begin{cases}
                        \text{脏腑}\\
                        \text{经络}\\
                        \text{精气神}
                    \end{cases}\\
                \text{疾病}
                    \begin{cases}
                        \text{病机}
                            \begin{cases}
                                \text{病因}\\
                                \text{发病}\\
                                \text{病理}\\
                                \text{传变}
                            \end{cases}\\
                        \text{病症}
                    \end{cases}
        \end{cases}\\
\text{医学基础}
        \begin{cases}
                \text{哲学}\\
                \text{天文历法}\\
                \text{地理学}\\
                \text{气象学}\\
                \text{数学}\\
                \text{社会学}
        \end{cases}\\
\end{cases}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brace diagram in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112175/brace-diagram-in-tikz)

Comment: @drat I don't think it is quite a duplicate - here the first and last text in each group is meant to be at the tips of the braces

Comment: @AndrewSwann Alain Matthes' answer seems to cover this.

Comment: The position of the tip of the braces is not consistent in the scan provided. They are placed at the "east" anchor of the first and last child, except in one case: `root-1-2-1`. But from the red marked parts, I guess that the OP is interested only in the first level.

Comment: I presume the problem is not specific to the Chinese (?) language. An example using a [standard document class](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1098/23160) and standard fonts would be easier to compile for a randomly selected TeX users.

Comment: Is also the 2nd brace from the top, 3rd column of braces, not aligned properly??  It extends above its top-most entry.  Just trying to understand the problem fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I use the schemata package to solve the problem. Though, not too perfect.

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{宋体}
%-----------------------------------------
\usepackage{schemata,xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\schema}
  {1.44265ex}{-1ex}
  {}{}
\newcommand\SC[2]{\schema{\schemabox{#1}}{\schemabox{#2}}}
\newcommand\SCh[4]{\Schema{#1}{#2}{\schemabox{#3}}{\schemabox{#4}}}
%-----------------------------------------

\begin{document}
{
\small\centerline{《内经》病因系统表}\smallskip
\label{fig:《内经》病因系统表}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\hspace{.1\textwidth}%左侧空白
\SCh{-5.7ex}{6ex}{致病因素}{\smallskip
        \SC{自然环境}{
            天气：风、雨、寒、暑、湿、燥、雾、露等\\
            天象：天宿失度，日月薄蚀，月郭圆缺\\
            地理：地域，地势
        }\\
        \SC{社会环境}{
            政治：政体，战争，职位\\
            经济：经济制度，贫富差异\\
            道徳：嗜欲无穷（物欲、权欲、色欲）\\
            心理：情志异常\\
            信仰：崇拜，迷信\\
            民俗：地区风气，生活习俗\\
            饮食：嗜食，偏食，饱食，冷食\\
            劳伤：体劳，房劳\\
            中毒：毒物（包括药物），醉酒}
}\hfill }


{
\label{fig:《内经》学术体系基本框架结构图}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\small
\hspace{.1\textwidth}%左侧距离
\SCh{9.5ex}{11.3ex}{《内经》学术体系}{
        \SCh{0.1ex}{13.7ex}{医学理论}{\smallskip
            \SC{藏象}{脏腑\\经络\\精气神}\\\smallskip
            \SCh{2.8ex}{2.9ex}{疾病}{
                \SC{病机}{病因\\发病\\病理\\传变}\\
                病症}\\\smallskip
            \SC{诊法}{\smallskip 诊病方法\\断病法则}\\\smallskip
            \SC{论治}{治则\\治法\\疗法\\测试}\\\smallskip
            \SC{养生}{\smallskip 摄生\\康复}
        }\\
        \SC{医学基础}{
            哲学\\
            天文历法\\
            地理学\\
            气象学\\
            数学\\
            社会学}
}\hfill }


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've made a start, using TikZ, though if I can be shown how this might be done more efficiently I would be grateful. Note that I am using **XeLaTeX** in TeXShop on a Mac. *This is not the complete chart*, and I make apologies if I have got any of the Chinese characters wrong. This is meant as a starting point.

```
    % !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Song Std L}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5em]
\node (main) at (0,0) {《内经》学术体系};
    \node (t1) at (1in,5\baselineskip) {医学理论};
    \node (t2) at (1in,-5\baselineskip) {医学基础};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (t1.west) -- (t2.west);
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=7\baselineskip] (st1) {藏象};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=2\baselineskip] (st2) {疾病};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=-1.5\baselineskip] (st3) {诊法};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=-4\baselineskip] (st4) {论治};
    \node [right =of t1,yshift=-6.5\baselineskip] (st5) {养生};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,aspect=0.525}] (st1.west) -- (st5.west);
    \node [right =of st1,yshift=1.5\baselineskip] (sst1) {脏腑};
    \node [right =of st1] (sst2) {经络};
    \node [right =of st1,yshift=-1.5\baselineskip] (sst3) {精气神};
    \node [right =of st2, yshift =1\baselineskip] (sst4){病机};
    \node [right =of st2, yshift =-2.5\baselineskip] (sst5){病证};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (sst1.west) -- (sst3.west);
    \node [right =of sst4, yshift=1.5\baselineskip] (ssst1) {病因};
    \node [right =of sst4, yshift=0.5\baselineskip] (ssst2) {发病};
    \node [right =of sst4, yshift=-0.5\baselineskip] (ssst3) {病理};
    \node [right =of sst4, yshift=-1.5\baselineskip] (ssst4) {传变};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (ssst1.west) -- (ssst4.west);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (sst4.west|-ssst1) -- (sst5.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Typeset table]

**WARNING** It does take a bit of fiddling to get this to come out the way you want it to.

**Some background and explanation:**

This problem shows off two powerful TikZ tools:

1. *Relative placement of nodes.* The `right = of * relieves gentle user of having to calculate distances and fiddle with dimensions. (Chapter 13 of the TikZ documention.)
2. Using the names of the nodes is also liberating in that you do not have to note precisely where a node is -- you just refer to its name. (Chapter 16 of the TikZ documentation.) The interesting part of this was in the fourth column of characters, the second group from the top: The bracket extends above the top pair of glyphs. This was accomplished with:

`\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (sst4.west|-ssst1) -- (sst5.west);`

which starts at `sst5.west` and extends to the x-coordinate off sst4.west but ends at the y-coordinate of ssst1.

I approached this by treating the original as columns of characters. Each vertical group could be broken up into smaller groups, and have brackets drawn next to them.

If I can find the time, I may finish this. I think all the hard work is done...