# Put a text into Brackets (no math mode)

Tags: math-mode, brackets

[image]

I want to make something like this. Put a text into Brackets (can be (). {}, [] ..., whatever type is the easiest).

I am looking for an easy way. There are a lot of similar question on this site, yet they need quite a lot of text writing.

Isn´t there any way like:

```
$\left\lbrace \text{something to write here, also $math$ in some parts of the text} \right\rbrace$
```

- but without the `$` and `\text{}`?
- Using MiKTeX Package (on Windows), so having the most packages available.

EDIT: The text put into Brackets will be a stand alone text (paragraph), no including in other text. So can be environments like `\begin{} \end{}`.

Comment: Sample text you can use: 

\textit{Beweis:} \\  
- Sei $f(a) = b$ injektiv. Setzen $g(b) = a$ injektiv.  $f\left(g(b)\right) = f(a) = b \Rightarrow f\circ g = id_B \Rrightarrow$ B.  Für $f\left(g(b)\right) \neq b$ gilt dies nicht. \\
- $g\left(f(a)\right) = g(b) = a \Rightarrow g\circ f = id_A \Rrightarrow$ A

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110391/27635

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that site. 
Yet the easiest answert there is like this: 
- use three packages (not that much of a problem)
- define a command (with 20 lines and only a manual brasket, that wont size as long as the text is)

I want a bracket, that automatically changes its size depending on the amount of lines it has to cover.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is very far from clear. Here's a hint:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This package is just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{braced}
 {\par\smallskip\hbox to\columnwidth\bgroup
  \hss$\left\{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}\right\}$\hss\egroup\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{braced}
\lipsum[3]
\end{braced}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The environment ends a possible preceding paragraph and inserts a small vertical space. Then it opens an `\hbox` as wide as the current `\columnwidth` (you may want to use `\linewidth` if you plan to use this inside a list environment). In this box math mode is started and `\left\{` is issued. Then a `minipage` is opened, as wide as `\columnwidth`. This finishes the starting part. The ending part closes the `minipage` and issues `\right\}` to balance the left delimiter and closes math mode; then the `\hbox` is closed and typeset. A small vertical space is added. Since `\hss` is added at either side of the math formula, the braces will be in the margins (the box is actually wider than `\columnwidth`, but the shrinkable glue provided by `\hss` makes it appear to fit).

Comment: Thats it. 
Would you mind explaining what exactly the \newenvironment{braced} does?

- left\{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}\right\}

I understand that part fully 
- embracing the environmentwidth with {} Great idea.

For what do you need the package "calc"?

Answer (score 5):

With `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{braced}[1][]{%
    colback=white,
%    boxrule=0pt,
%    boxsep=0pt,
    blanker,
    frame code={
        \draw [line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=2pt,mirror}]
            (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
        \draw [line width=1pt,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=2pt}]
            (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);
        },
    width=\linewidth,
    before=\par\smallskip\noindent,
    after={},
    %breakable,
    #1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{braced}
\lipsum[3]
\end{braced}

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]