# Table enclosed in curly brackets

Tags: tables, formatting, matrices, brackets

I would like to enclose a table with curly brackets. I photoshopped an example here:
[image: Table Curly Brackets]

The MWE of the table is here, please feel free to add packages etc.

`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{0.7cm} p{8cm}}

$D_{1}~Value Proposition$ & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
$D_{2}~Value Proposition$ & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You don't want to use the `table` environment here -- that's a "float", and can't be placed inside anything else.  Just `tabular` should work, although to get the braces around it, it will need to be embedded in math (a display as you have shown) with `\text{...}` around the `tabular` block.

Comment: `texdoc schemata`, there are a example of use [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120155/11604)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\verysloppy}{\tolerance=2000 \hbadness=2000 \emergencystretch=\linewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Taxonomy}_1=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\mbox{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}l<{$} l >{$}r<{{}$} @{} >{\verysloppy}p{8cm}@{}}
  D_{1} & Value Proposition & D_1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  D_{2} & Value Proposition & D_2 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  D_{3} & Value Proposition & D_3 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  D_{4} & Value Proposition & D_4 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  D_{5} & Value Proposition & D_5 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  D_{6} & Value Proposition & D_6 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you. When I add the table to my document, it fits very nicely. But the right bracket is not aligned with my linewidth, it overshoots. Only the text is aligned correctly

Comment: @slandolt Reduce the size of the last column

Answer (score 4):

Just place your tabular inside a math environment like `\[\]` and use `\left\{` and `\right\}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\[\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{0.7cm} p{8cm}}

$D_{1}~Value Proposition$ & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
$D_{2}~Value Proposition$ & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform, C1,9 Decision Support System,,C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database, C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
\end{tabular}\right\}\]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Added the `\text{Taxonomy=}` and broken manually the long lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begingroup
\centering
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\[\text{Taxonomy=}\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{0.7cm} l}

$D_{1}$~\emph{Value Proposition} & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform,\\ &&C1,9 Decision Support System,,\\&&C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database,\\&& C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
$D_{2}$~\emph{Value Proposition} & D1 = & \{C1,7 Blockchain, C1,8 Digital Platform,\\ &&C1,9 Decision Support System,,\\&&C1,10 Marketplace, C1,11 Database,\\&& C1,12 Transaction Processing, System\} \\
\end{tabular}\right\}\]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tank you very much! But am I able to add the "Taxonomy =" in a tabular environment?

Comment: See my edit but I think there are better ways too have what you want.