# different color of brackets

Tags: math-mode, color

I need an advice..
I need to recreate the following formula:
[image]

The only difference is that color of the brackets needs to be red.
Is it neccessary to do this in math mode, or can be achieved in some other way ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I dont have it.. thats why I'm asking for advice.. don't know even where to start.. I'm a beginner in Latex

Comment: Also related/possible duplicate: [Stretchable square brackets outside math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30024/4301)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it neccessary to do this in math mode?

It would certainly simplify doing some things, such as the sizing of the large square brackets.

The following solution is based on the macro `\colvec`, which is defined in the preamble. It assumes that it's encountered in math mode. It uses `\color` directives to switch between red and black and it uses an `array` environment to "stack" the contents. Note that the `\colvec` macro is designed to be nestable; hence, it can be used both for the outer structure and the three inner structures. The text material inside each `\colvec` is handled using `\textsc` (for smallcaps) and `\textbf` (for boldface) directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,xcolor}
\newcommand{\colvec}[1]{ % % to be used in math mode
  \color{red}\left[\color{black}
    \begin{array}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{array}
  \color{red}\right]\color{black}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$ % start math mode
\colvec{%
  \alpha \\
  \textsc{argstr} =
    \colvec{
      \textsc{arg}1 = x\\
      \dots}\\[2ex] % a bit of extra vertical space
  \textsc{eventstr} = 
    \colvec{%
      \textsc{e}1 = e_1 \\
      \dots}\\[2ex] % ditto
  \textsc{qualia} = 
    \colvec{%
      \textsc{const} = \textbf{what $x$ is made of}\\
      \textsc{formal} = \textbf{what $x$ is}\\
      \textsc{telic} = \textbf{function of $x$}\\
      \textsc{agentive} = \textbf{how $x$ came into being}}
  }
$ % end math mode
\end{center}
\end{document}
```